# WP_EDITOR content is not captured

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to change the default theme editor (`jqte`) to the WP editor, but the edited content is not updating upon form submission.

Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
ob_start();
$editor_id = 'ad_description'; // Unique ID for the editor
$settings = array(
    'textarea_name' => 'job_description', // Name of the textarea field
    'textarea_rows' => 10, // Number of rows for the textarea
    'media_buttons' => true, // Whether to include media upload buttons
    'quicktags' => true, // Whether to include quicktags (HTML shortcuts)
);

wp_editor($description, $editor_id, $settings);

         $output = ob_get_contents();
         echo $output;
```

The submission works when I use static data instead of `$description`. Although `$description` has data in it and I was able to retrieve data from it.

```
$post = get_post($job_id);
$description = $post->post_content;
```

I also tried to use `ob_get_clean()` with no luck.

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Give us the code in the order you actually have it. In your block, you're not showing where `$description` is coming from. Show us the full function.